# illegal text-relocoation (direct reference) to (global,weak) for architecture i386

Tags: ffmpeg, xcode6, ios-simulator, clang, ld

Searching about shows this error in a number of mailing lists, but neither a general solution nor explanation is forthcoming.

What does `illegal text-relocoation (direct reference) to (global,weak)` mean and how can it be resolved.

Specifically, I have built ffmpeg-2.5.2 using [this script](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script). When building XCode tests that use it, there is the following error:

```
ld: illegal text-relocoation (direct reference) to (global,weak)
    _ff_h264_cabac_tables in <...>/myLib.a(cabac.o)
    from _ff_h264_decode_mb_cabac in <...>/myLib.a(h264_cabac.o)
    for architecture i386
```

Does this require compiler/linker options to fix, or some kind of code change?

Comment: N.B. if that is a typo of "relocation", then it's a typo in clang

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `-read_only_relocs suppress` to the app's linker flags allows a successful build.

Comment: I got `-read_only_relocs and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together` what can you do when you need to use bitcode?